# Code First One to One Relationship and MVC Create Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have a code first database. The tables causing me issues are

```
public class Deadline
{
    public Deadline() { }
    public Deadline(Year year)
    {
        this.Year = year;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Year Year { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Date]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Date]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}

public class Year
{
    public Year(Int32 value) { this.Value = value; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Year")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Year]        
    public Int32 Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Deadline Deadline { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller for the year which has the create get method

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Deadline, "Id", "Id");
        var Year = new Year(db.Year.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().Value + 1);
        Year.Deadline = new Deadline(Year);
        return View(Year);
    }
```

and the post method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Year year)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (db.Year.Select(x => x.Value).Contains(year.Value))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("AlreadyExists", "That year has already been added to the database, please edit instead");
                return View(year);
            }
            db.Year.Add(year);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(year);
    }
```

Whenever i try to create a new Year though (having set the year value and the deadline dates) it gets back to the post and the modelstate is invalid and says

> The Year field is required.

I've checked and at the post method year.Deadline.Year is indeed null, what i want to know is why (and how i can fix this) it's been driving me crazy, even putting

```
@{ Model.Deadline.Year = Model; }
```

in the view did nothing.

**Edit** The following works

```
    using (ProjectSelectionAndAllocation.Models.DatabaseContext Context = new Models.DatabaseContext())
    {
        var h = new Models.Year(1001);
        h.Deadline = new Models.Deadline(h);
        Context.Year.Add(h);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about the mistag if your viewing before it changes, for some reason it submitted whilst i was tagging

Comment: Model.Deadline.Year = Model doesn't seem valid.  Model isn't a Year, is it?  What is the original code for the View?

Comment: model is a year, the controller is for the Year and its @model Namespace.Models.Year, i haven't changed the original code was just trying that line to see if setting it in the view worked

Comment: Well i havent changed the view much, just so that it shows a edit field for the deadline to and from

Comment: have you tried your code-first code/adding if it's working properly and not issues w/ the Db / model. And what does you view/cshtml do?

Comment: @NSGaga added a edit, I have sucessfully added Year with deadline using the code.

Comment: @NSGaga the view successfully submits it but the modelstate is invalid because for some reason the deadline.Year isn't persisting

Comment: so the model is not valid and it fails as I see - something's not lost in between the view and back seems, hard to tell w/o debugging

Comment: @NSGaga When i breakpoint in the view it is set as it should be, so somehow when pressing the submit button and before getting to the httppost method the value is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have two basic theories as to the problem but one solution that you should implement anyway.

So I'll start with the solution:  Use a ViewModel.  That is a small, flat, lightweight class that just contains the fields the view wants to display.  It should not be the same as your data layer.  The view should just be rendering stuff, and the ViewModel should just contain the data to be displayed.

You'll map the data from your actual objects to the ViewModel (AutoMapper is pretty popular for this.)

Now, why will this help?  Well, my theories as to your problem are:

1) The model binder might not like virtual properties.  Whenever you return a form to a function in MVC there's little bit of code that runs through and tries to map all the values in the form to their fields.  This model binder might be unable to figure out a virtual field or there might be some good reason not to automatically map to one.  Either way, a ViewModel would replace this with a regular public property.

2) The other possibility, but I'm not too sure of it, is that there is a circular reference (Year -> Deadline -> Year ) and the model binder doesn't handle that well.  Again though, the ViewModel concept would get rid of that and you'd just have a Year field in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me when my model wasn't wired up properly in the view.  This kinda thing will prevent the model binder from materializing the model on the post action.  One thing to check is to make sure your using good asp.net mvc naming conventions in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had in mind, it's often proving useful when you don't know what's happening...
reference to a post with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10037334/417747
...

in similar cases when the binding doesn't work as expected, often helps to debug - and that by making a custom binder.

```
public class YearClassBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    //public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    //{
    //}
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var model = (Year)base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);

        // ...you change, inspect set etc.

        return model;
    }
}
```

...this is the way to custom bind, adjust your 'passing' values - also check if problems with them etc.
(you'd need to test, try a few options, might be BindModel that's better, depends)

(you have more details within that link)

It's not an exact answer but will get you on the right track, most of the time.

hope it helps.

**EDIT: just to add**, you could use this same approach to manually adjust and create the Year instance if needed and in case of any problems like one poster mentioned (cyclical references etc.).